# Zip Two dict contain a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have n number of dict which contain value as list like

```
{"1":[{'q': ['Data'], 'q1': '110'}]}

{"2":[{'q2':["other Data"], "q3" : "exp"},{'q2':["other Data2"], "q3" : "exp2"}]}
```

I want output in this format:-

```
{"1":[{'q': ['Data'], 'q1': '110'}],"2":[{'q2':["other Data"], "q3" : "exp"}]}
{"2":{'q2':["other Data2"], "q3" : "exp2"}
```

Means zip or we can split basis of dict key and add only one value for each key if present.

Comment: Your desired output is missing some closing brackets, and your data structure is already confusing enough without typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `dict1.update(dict2)` any use to you?  This will simply update `dict1` with the  values in `dict2`.

EDIT:

This might work:

```
dicts=[]
dicts.append({"1":[{'q': ['Data'], 'q1': '110'}]})
dicts.append({"2":[{'q2':["other Data"], "q3" : "exp"},{'q2':["other Data2"], "q3" : "exp2"}]})

a=[[{key: j} for key in d2 for j in d2[key]] for d2 in dicts ]

nmax=max(len(x) for x in a)

newdicts=[dict() for i in range(nmax)]

for i in range(nmax):    
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i < len(a[j]):    
            newdicts[i].update(a[j][i])

for i in newdicts:
    print i
```

Which gives me:

```
{'1': {'q': ['Data'], 'q1': '110'}, '2': {'q3': 'exp', 'q2': ['other Data']}}
{'2': {'q3': 'exp2', 'q2': ['other Data2']}}
```

Comment: I have lists of value in dict so I want to split contain equal number of values in a key